# Q: When i use cordova-plugin-ble-central.I write on ios but it return 'null'

Tags: ios, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova-plugin-ble-contral,I write on ios but it return 'null',on android return 'ok'.I can not write well on ios.

I can write well on android and ios, I make hybird APP.

```
  connectTo() {
  var that = this;

  var Hex = "";
  Hex += addZero(stringToSixteen(this.ssid), 32);
  Hex += "07";
  Hex += addZero(stringToSixteen(this.password), 64);
  Hex += "A5A5";

  var data = HexString2Bytes(Hex);
  let length = Math.ceil(data.byteLength / 20); 
  var success = function(reason) {
    // it will return null? 
    that.$router.push({
      name: "isConnect",
      query: {
        deviceId: that.deviceId,
        ssid: that.ssid,
        password: that.password
      }
    });
  };
  var failure = function(reason) {
     alert(reason);
    that.$router.push({
      name: "isConnect",
      query: {
        deviceId: that.deviceId,
        ssid: that.ssid,
        password: that.password
      }
    });
  };

  //分包发送msg
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var buffers = data.slice(i * 20, (i + 1) * 20);
    ble.writeWithoutResponse(
      this.deviceId,
      this.serviceUUID,
      this.characteristicToWrite,
      buffers,
      success,
      failure
    );
  }
},
```

It show I write well but it does not send message in fact.

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Aria_1010 do mean cordova-plugin-ble-central. I can't find any plugin with name "cordova-plugin-ble-contral".